# How do I reserve ports for my application?

Tags: tcp, udp, socket

How do I reserve a list of ports for my custom applications?

To be specific, the product I'm creating has a lot of processes and a lot of intercommunication between them.

The problem I'm having is that - every once in a while - the OS steals my ports.  It's rare, but it happens.

This could be because a different application has used "::bind" with no port specified.

Or sometimes my own applications steal the port when I call "::connect" with an unbound socket.  As seen from the man page:

> If  the  socket  has  not  already  been bound to a local address, connect() shall bind it to an address
>         which, unless the socket's address family is AF_UNIX, is an unused local address.

So my question is, can I reserve the ports that I need so the OS doesn't use them?  Can this be accomplished with /etc/services?  Or is there a different way?

Comment: Can you use AF_UNIX sockets instead?

Comment: More worried why your own application is 'stealing ports'?

Comment: I was debating if I need to go through my software and bind the client side of each connection to a specific port.  It's quite the job for me to update this as there are a *lot* of connection paths in my applications.   Reserving ports in the OS would have been a good stop gap solution until I found time to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure if `SELinux` in Enforcing mode can meet your requirement, I'm still learning on it. So just a guess, maybe you can define your own policy for `SELinux` to *reserve* yours ports, such as `my_server_port_t   tcp  1111, 2222, 3333, 4444-4600`. If your application will run everywhere (not a server application), I'm afraid you can't control whether `SELinux` is ON or OFF.

Comment: By "stealing" I assume you mean that the 3rd party app is binding to your chosen port number before you application gets  a chance, because the 3rd party app has requested to bind to 0 and the OS has randomly assigned your chosen port number to the 3rd party app. If so, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38724/27865

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Technically, there's no such thing as a "reserved port".

In TCP/UDP, the only way to "reserve" a port is to actually `bind()` a socket to it.  A bound port will not be used by other applications; an unused port is, well, unused so other applications are free to use it.

If you are writing server software, then you can bind your sockets to specific ports as early as you want in the application code.  Make the port numbers configurable, or at least clearly state them in the documentation, so that a systems administrator can quickly identify clashes and move conflicting applications to separate servers.

Comment: Also, avoid using well known/reserved ports if at all possible.

Comment: There are reserved ports sometimes.  This is good general advice but not the correct answer on Linux.

Answer (score 28):

To ensure the kernel won't give out 49000 and 49001 to clients as you wish to use them for your servers on linux.

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports = 49000, 49001
```

drop it in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, and then run `sysctl -p`.

Note that this is untested.

#### References

- [Documentation / networking / ip-sysctl.txt](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt)

Comment: I tried this, but it also prevented my own application from using the ports! What about defining the port numbers with names in `/etc/services`?

Comment: @user134197 This should not prevent your own application from using those ports if you explicitly use a non zero port number in your bind request. It works for me.

Answer (score 16):

Actually, the above answer is not entirely accurate.  The sysctls net.inet.ip.portrange.first and net.inet.ip.portrange.last specify the range of ports the OS can allocate for random ports.  You would want to make sure that the range of reserved ports for your application does not fall within these variables.

Take a look in the FreeBSD Handbook, section: [12.14. Tuning Kernel Limits](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/configtuning-kernel-limits.html).
But the same basic premise should apply to Linux as well.

Comment: Also, this link may be of assistance:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913501/how-to-let-kernel-choose-a-port-number-in-the-range-1024-5000-in-tcp-socket-pr

Comment: I think in Linux it's called `net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range`